# blogengine changes in app_data and tfs conflict?

Tags: tfs, blogengine.net

All the setup and blogs are stored in xml files under app_data folder as shown in the image. When I do administrative set up or new blog, it will be written on the webserver but I have my project in the TFS and next publish to the webserver will overwrite those changes. I know that there is an option that dont publish app_data but it means that my latest app_data version will never be in the Tfs but in the server. I wonder if there is anyway to syncronize this issue beside doing it manually.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a get (copy app_data from live to TFS) before you make any edits.

You would be better using a host that supports Git as a content management solution. You can then just sync and merge like you would with a branch.

Comment: "You would be better using a host that supports Git as a content management solution".  what do you mean by that? you advise me to use Git instead of TFS?

Comment: No AND. TFS is not a source control system. It lets you choose between TFVC and GIT which are. You can create a Team Project with Git and hook it up so that you can more easily manage your web application. I only sugest as you have content as code.